# Smooth scroll to the top of page script after form validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, function

I have a long form and I would like to scroll up to the top of the page using my jquery smooth-scroll-to-the-top-of-page script.

Is it possible to scroll to the top of page **if the validation script finds errors**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your smooth scroll a function that can be called onError i.e

```
function SmoothScroll(){
 $('a.scrollToTop').click(function () {
   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
   }, 2500);
  return false;
 });
}
```

and

```
    onError: function () {
        if ($('#input_2     input').hasClass('error-input')) {
            $('#r2 div, #r2 input').css('background-color', '#C1272D').css('color', '#FFF');
            $("#error-div").show();
            SmoothScroll();
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I follow your instruction, I loose my validation and the page jumps up tot the top without the scroll.  I loose the validation and no smooth scroll.  Trying to figure this out...

Comment: What happens when you add timeout? window.setTimeout(smootScroll, 2000);

Comment: Not sure how or where you add that..  Does it go in the beginning?